# nginx: 403 forbidden for a particular text value for Location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am facing a strange issue with nginx configuration.

Everything works. But if I change value for location directive (while keeping everything absolutely identical), it fails.

So following configuration works:

```
location ~ ^/v1/works/(.*)$ {
  ...
  ...
}
```

But not this:

```
location ~ ^/v1/doesnotwork/(.*)$ {
  ...
  ...
}
```

I get this error log:

```
access forbidden by rule, client: 100.97.0.0, server: my-host.com, request: "GET /v1/doesnotwork HTTP/1.1", host: "my-host.com"
```

It seems some rule allows a particular word ("works" in this example), but forbids usage of another word ("doesnotwork" in this example) for location directive.

What could be the cause? What part of nginx configuration in general or proxy_pass configuration in particular can make it possible to have such rule?

Comment: You may have typed your question incorrectly, but the regular expression in `location ~ ^/v1/doesnotwork/(.*)$` does not match `GET /v1/doesnotwork`. There is no trailing `/`. Is there a mechanism to append a trailing `/` elsewhere in your configuration file?

Comment: Sorry @RichardSmith. I didn't get your question. In my posting, both configurations are identicall, except the words - works and doesnotwork. Both contains '/' after the word.

To give you more detail, the not working configuration is like:

    location ~ ^/v1/doesnotwork/(.*)$ {
      set $upstream http://some-other-host:8080;
      proxy_pass $upstream/$1$is_args$args;
    }

Comment: I am getting a feeling that the upstream application has some configuration which has dependency on original requested url.

Comment: There is no trailing `/` on the URI in your error log - is that a typo in the question?

Comment: Aah. It 's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.

The cause was multi-occurrence of server block for the same domain.

The original author was first trying to use some services from test environment and some other from prod. After testing it, finally corrected the servers. But he had forgotten to merge the 2 blocks into one.

The re-occurence of server domain and also re-occurence of some of the location directives was causing the goof-up.

On consolidating all these location to single server block the issue got resolved.